# pygradle: Multi-Project-Example: buildPex FAILED when using project dependency

Tags: python, gradle, gradle-plugin, pygradle

i would like to use pygradle in a multi-project setup with project dependencies. I created two gradle sub-projects. A python-cli project (example-app) and a python-sdist project (example-lib) on which the cli project depends on.

But currently i'm facing the following error ([gist](https://gist.github.com/kKdH/a53a3b0ed471e9e9919070b76b893282)) when i try to build the app:

```
multi-project-example/example-app> gradle build --info

> Task :example-app:buildPex FAILED
Task ':example-app:buildPex' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Starting process 'command '/home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/python''. Working directory: /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app Command: /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/python /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/pip freeze --all --disable-pip-version-check
Successfully started process 'command '/home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/python''
/home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/deployable/bin/example-app.pex
Starting process 'command '/home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/python''. Working directory: /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app Command: /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/python /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/pex --no-pypi --cache-dir /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/pex-cache --output-file /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/deployable/bin/example-app.pex --repo /home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/wheel-cache --python-shebang /home/kkdh/.anaconda3/bin/python UNKNOWN==0.0.0 example-app==0.3.0a1
Successfully started process 'command '/home/kkdh/Projects/pygradle/examples/multi-project-example/example-app/build/venv/bin/python''
Could not satisfy all requirements for example-lib:
    example-lib(from: example-app==0.3.0a1)
:example-app:buildPex (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 1.165 secs.
```

You will find the example in my fork of pygradle: https://github.com/kKdH/pygradle/tree/master/examples/multi-project-example

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/issues/301) about this problem but without any response from the project maintainers. So now i'am asking here for any pointers to a solution or further troubleshoot steps.